# How to allow user to change backgroundImage in app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, background-image, asyncstorage

I'm new in this technology and I'm writing Todo App in React Native and I'm searching how to allow user to change backgroundImage and saving changes in my app with available images. I don't know how to do it. Can somebody help me? Please, something material which can help me or tips. Thank you!

Comment: You can achieve this using state.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list of images in your public folder you can do this:

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
       imagePath: "/image-name",
   }
}
```

In render, you can render the image this way
    `<img src="${this.state.imagePath}" alt="my-image"/>`

And then you have a function that updates the state

```
const handleChange = (newImage: string) => {
   this.setState({
       imagePath: newImage,
   });
}
```

And whenever you want to change the image, through a button click or something, you call the handleChange function and pass in the new imagePath. This will set the state, which in return will re-render the application, with the new image.

Comment: Thank you, I check this! :)